# IntelliJ shortkey for java lambda expression

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, shortcut

Is there any shortkey available in IntelliJ IDEA for typing lambda expression in the editor?

> To create an arrow, i have to type `-` and `>` to get an lamda
>   expression.

```
List<T> someList;

someList.forEach(item ->{
   // do something
});
```

which I see as time consuming.

I need to create a shortkey for this , so that I can save time in creating lambda expression while coding. I am new to IntelliJ IDEA and I need to know is there any way to create custom shortkey for this purpose.

Comment: i think , the question is clear ,asking for ways to create custom short keys in intellji, and down vote for this?. why close. down voter need to answer this..

Comment: Have a look at "Live Templates"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a live template, from `Preferences > Editor > Live Templates`.

Here's a screenshot showing a live template definition:

[image]

In this example I have associated the shortcut "lda" with the following code block:

```
item -> {}
```

You can expand this live template with the `TAB` key.

Here's a screeshot showing it's appearance in intellisense:

[image]

Here's a screenshot showing the code after this live termplate has been selected:

[image]

Comment: `lda<tab>` four keys to press, `x<space>->`  four keys to press, ok, three keys to save if you always name your variable `item`, but it doesn’t work for lambda expression having a different number of parameters. What a big deal…

Comment: In addition, I'd add that you can write the template like `$ITEM$ -> {$BODY$}` in order to rename the parameter and make it easier to navigate through the lambda expression.